# Jquery compare data/object differences on checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a checkbox to hihglight the differences between data inside a div rather than table.

So if row has differences "Single, Single, Married" this should be highlighted.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ly61u493/1/

Logic:

```
$('.check-diff').click(function() {
if($(this).prop('checked')){
    //highlight status except header
    alert("Bang highlight it...");
} else{
    //unchecked should remove the highlight areas
    alert("Not highlighted");
}
});

    <label for="">Click to see differences</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="check-diff">
<div class="compare-diff">
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="col-sm-3 title">Name</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">John</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Henry</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Kim</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 title">Status</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Single</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Married</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Single</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 title">Car</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your question? What problem have you encountered?

Comment: So you are saying first 2 rows has to be **highligted**?

Answer (score 1):

how about the following jquery code?

```
$('.check-diff').click(function() {
if($(this).prop('checked')){
    checkDiff();
} else{
    $(".row").each(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#fff");
    });
}
});

function checkDiff(){
$(".row").each(function(){
    var diff = false;
    var source = $(this).find(".diff").first().text();
    $(this).find(".diff").each(function(){
        var compare = $(this).text();
        if(source != compare){
           diff = true;
        }
    });   
    if(diff == true){
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    }
 });
}
```

hope i got you right and you get an idea, how to move on! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 each loops and a class name for the rows you want to check. Only `row` that has a class name `checkDiff` will be validated and cells that has a class name `diff`.

[**JSnippet DEMO** - validate difference in rows base on the cell text](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/342/validate-difference-in-rows-base-on-the-cell-text)

JS:

```
$(function(){

    $('.check-diff').click(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $('.row.checkDiff').each(function(i,ele){
                var values = $(ele).find('.diff');
                var first = values.eq(0).text();
                var diff = false;
                values.each(function(j,e){
                    if ($(e).text() !== first) diff = true;
                });
                if (diff) $(ele).addClass('highlight');
            });
        } else{
            $('.row.checkDiff').removeClass('highlight');
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="">Click to see differences</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="check-diff">
<div class="compare-diff">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 title">Name</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">John</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Henry</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">Kim</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row checkDiff">
        <div class="col-sm-3 title">Status</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Single</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Married</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Single</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row checkDiff">
            <div class="col-sm-3 title">Car</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row checkDiff">
            <div class="col-sm-3 title">Kids</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">No</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row checkDiff">
            <div class="col-sm-3 title">Home</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 diff">Yes</div>
    </div>
</div>
```